# PHP $_POST undefined variable (using JQuery AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, post

I submit my form with JQuery Ajax in php as this :

```
    $("#addForm").submit( function() {  
    //var valid = jQuery("#addForm").validationEngine('validate');
    var valid = true;
        if(valid==true) {
        // recuperer toutes les informations 
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var type = $('select#type option:selected').val();
        var region = $('select#region option:selected').val();
        var level = $('select#level option:selected').val();
        var nbPers = $("#number_person").val();
        var tempsPre = $("#time_pre").val();
        var tempsC = $("#time_c").val();
        var ings = $("#ing_hide").val();
        var etapes = $("#preparation").val();

        $.ajax({ 
             type: "POST", 
                 url: "php/add.php", 
             data: "name="+name+"&type="+type+"&region="+region+"&level="+level+"&nbPers="+nbPers+"&tempsPre="+tempsPre+"&tempsCui="+tempsC+"&ings="+ings+"&etapes="+etapes, 

         error : function(request, error) {      
          alert("Erreur : responseText: "+request.responseText);
  },            
        success: function(msg){ // si l'appel a bien fonctionné
                            alert('ok');
            }
        });
        return false; 

        } else {
           alert('error');
           return false;      
        }
 });
```

when I debug using firebug, all my variables were correct

but in php files , the var_dump show : undefined for `var_dump($_POST['name']);` and correct value for `var_dump($_POST['ings']);`

Note: I dont use `isset` because I'm only testing that the variable contains value in first

Why I've undefined ?

My HTML form :

```
<div class="row field_text">
                    <label class="label_title">Nom  :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="inputtext" name="name" id="name"/>
                </div>

                <div class="row field_select">
                    <label class="label_title">Type :</label>
                    <select class="select_styled" name="type" id="type">
                        <option value="1">E</option>
                        <option value="2">P</option>
                        <option value="3">D</option>
                        <option value="4">B</option>                       
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <label>Region</label>
                    <select class="select_styled" name="region" id="region">
                        <option value="1">Ma</option>
                        <option value="2">Eu</option>
                        <option value="3">Af</option>
                        <option value="4">Mo</option>
                        <option value="5">As</option>                                        
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="row field_select">
                    <label class="label_title">Difficulté :</label>
                    <select class="select_styled" name="level" id="level">
                        <option value="1">F</option>
                        <option value="2">M</option>
                        <option value="3">D</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="row field_text">
                    <label class="label_title">Nombre Personne :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="inputtext" name="number_person" id="number_person"/>
                </div>

                <div class="row field_text">
                    <label class="label_title">Temps pré :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="inputtext" name="time_pre" id="time_pre"/>
                </div>

                <div class="row field_text">
                    <label class="label_title">Temps cui :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="inputtext" name="time_cook" id="time_cook"/>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="ings_div">
                    <div class="row field_select">
                        <label for="ingredient" class="label_title">Ingrédient :</label>
                        <select id="ingredient" name="basic-combo"  size="1" class="select_styled">
                            <?php include('php\liste-ingredients.php');?>
                      </select>     
                    </div>



                    <div class="row field_text">
                        <label class="label_title">Quantité :</label>
                        <input id="quantite" type="text" class="inputtext" name="recette_quantite"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row field_select">
                        <label class="label_title">Unité :</label>
                        <select id="unite" class="select_styled" name="unite">
                            <?php include('php/liste-unites.php'); ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row rowSubmit">
                        <input id="btn_add_ing" type="submit" value="+">
                    </div>



                    <div class="rowIng">
                        <label class="label_title">Liste Ingrédients :</label>
                        <textarea id="recette_ingredient" class="textareaField required" name="recette_ingredient" cols="5" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="rowIngHide">
                        <label class="label_title">Liste Ingrédients :</label>
                        <textarea id="recette_ingredient_hide" class="textareaField required" name="recette_ingredient_hide" cols="5" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="preparation_div">

                    <div class="">
                        <label class="label_title">Préparation :</label>
                        <textarea class="textareaField required" name="preparation" id="preparation" cols="8" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>


                <div class="row rowSubmit">
                    <span class="btn btn_search"><input type="submit" value="Ajouter"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: First try to print in your php0 file like var_dump($_POST); and check you are getting variables(value) properly.

Comment: What does your php lookm like. And you can pass the data more easyly with serialize: `data: $(this).serialize()` where this refers to the form element because you are in `$('#addform').submit();`.

Comment: I've this :

`
array (size=9)
  'name' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'type' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'region' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'level' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'nbPers' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'tempsPre' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'tempsCui' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
  'ings' => string '4,8,1
' (length=6)
  'etapes' => string 'undefined' (length=9`

Comment: Then your html inputs seem not to be correct. Could you add them to your question?

Comment: My php file is like this :

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Enregistrer les erreurs dans un fichier de log
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
// Nom du fichier qui enregistre les logs (attention aux droits à l'écriture)
ini_set('error_log', 'C:wamp/www/CookTrader/php/log_error_php.txt');
// Afficher les erreurs et les avertissements
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


//var_dump($_POST['name']);
//var_dump($_POST['ings']);
var_dump($_POST);


$name=$_POST['name'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$region=$_POST['region'];
........

Comment: Edit this into your answer.

Comment: First check whether you will be getting value in your javascript variable or not because if as per your output i can see you are getting only value for  'etapes' variable. Can you post your html code so that i can help you out.

Comment: I've add my html form in my answer

Comment: I think the problem is in the following line: `url: "php/add.php"`

Comment: Where is your starting `<form>` tag?

Comment: @Leonardo Can't be because he gets some values.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer my bad then, I didn't read the entire post.

Comment: <form action="#" class="search_form clearfix" id="addForm">